# Set ContentPlaceHoderId from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using to master pages for specific page like ( before login and after login).I dynamically managed to set two different master pages for specific page...but i stil have to set contentplaceholder as dynamically from code behind....Is that is possible? if yes? how could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is

You should create a user control for  (before login and after login )

and set that user conterol according to session in code behind.

```
ContentPlaceHolder placeholder = Page.Master.FindControl(“ContentPlaceHolder1″) as         ContentPlaceHolder;
```

by getting this placeholder  you can do what ever you want like add new control or find control in that placeholder,etc.